# Compile Python functions with numpy lib using Cython

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cpython, cythonize

I have python function, using numpy module. For example

```
import numpy as np

cdef public void test():
    x = np.linspace(-4, 4, shapness)
```

And i have **main.c** function, calling **test** function.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "test.h"

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("Initializing Python Runtime...\n");
    Py_Initialize ();
    inittest();

    test();

    printf ("Cleanup...\n");
    Py_Finalize ();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling all with **cython**

```
cython test.pyx -o test.c
gcc -o app main.c test.c `python-config --includes --ldflags`
```

When i'm running exe file, i'v got an error

```
Exception NameError: "name 'np' is not defined" in 'test.test' ignored
```

How i can compile all with numpy lib.

Comment: Relevant related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962278/cython-calling-python-code-from-c-program and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43372151/cython-importing-cython-modules-and-merging-them-into-single-shared-object